# Creating random clicks and moments to simulate human behavior- Scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I'm looking for some help in improving my spider so it won't repeat obvious patterns of grabbing data making the activity look like bots. So basically random mouse movements, clicks, and maybe some scrolling. Every article I've read suggests this, but I've yet to see any real code implementations. So if anyone has ever incorporated this practice I'd really appreciate some pointers.

So far I've been looking into pyautogui and [Bézier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) with no luck.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is overkill for most antibot systems, but such activity should be reproducible with any headless browser (e.g. Pupetteer, Selenium). Antibot systems employing JavaScript can usually detect that you are using them, though, unless you take some measures to hide that fact somehow, which not all headless browsers allow.

Comment: Thanks im currently implementing selenium action driver to move the mouse around. It does kinda defeat the purpose of avoiding detection tho if the framework is an obvious flag